# Should i add file upload size in current file without adding php.ini & htaccess on server

Tags: php, file, file-upload

Is it possible to work when i add `post_max_size` , `upload_max_filesize` & `memory_limit` in current file without adding it in `php.ini` and .`htaccess` file on server.

Because i have added those things in both of file but still i am facing issue during upload file.

I have added following code in php.ini

```
memory_limit = 10242M
upload_max_filesize = 10242M
post_max_size = 10242M
```

But not work then after i have added following code in my current file.

```
ini_set("post_max_size", "30M");
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "30M");
ini_set("memory_limit", "20000M");
```

But both thing are not working still i am facing issue during upload file , I faced following error during upload video file.

```
 [product_video] => Array
        (
            [name] => big_buck_bunny.mp4
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )
```

This is working perfect in my local system but problem on server side.

Is anybody help me what's i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After changing in php.ini file make sure you are restarting apache over server.

Answer (score 0):

You should restart `php-fpm` service to update your PHP setting.

If you're using Ubuntu

`sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`